# LocalStorage does not persist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage, state

I have been trying to persist my token in the localStorage but everytime I referesh the page, the value turns to undefined.

Here is my code from `App.tsx`. I am using redux in my project but persisting using redux throws plenty of type errors. That is why I am going with local storage.

```
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState('');
  // @ts-ignore
  const user = useAppSelector(state=>state.user.currentUser.token);
  useEffect(()=>{
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if(getToken){
      setIsLoggedIn(getToken)
    }
  },[])

  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("token", user)
  },[user])
```

For extra reference, these are my routes

```
        <Route path="/userProfile" element={<UserProfile />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Login />} />
        <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/product/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
```

So far I have tried all that I know but I am still not able to figure out the root problem.

Comment: put a `console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"))` just after `localStorage.setItem("token", user)` to really see what's happening

Comment: It renders undefined. I guess its because on every re-render, setItem in useEffect tries to set the token again. Since its initial state is defined as empty string in the useState hook. it just replaces it with empty the strings.

Comment: `It renders` what render? I suggested a console.log not a render

Comment: It logs undefined.

Comment: initially i can see the token stored in localStroage. But on refreshing the page, it disappears.

Comment: is `localStorage.setItem("token", user)` the only place you `setItem`? if so, that's what is clearing it

Comment: It's the ```user``` dependency. Every time it updates, local storage updates. So your should put some checks on it. Is the ```user``` identifier ```null or undefined``` maybe do some type checks. At the same time check if user is a ```string``` or ```object```. LocalStorage can't process objects directly. You might want to ```stringify``` the user. Should fix your issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem("token", user)
  },[user])
```

Your problem is from the above `useEffect`. Although it has dependency `user` (which is listening to `user` state changes), it's called when you render the component for the first time.

I'd propose you should add a condition to that `useEffect` like below

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    if(user) {
       localStorage.setItem("token", user)
    }
  },[user])
```

That would help you to prevent calling `setItem` with an undefined value of `user`.

Answer (score 1):

Check user to undefined

```
user && localStorage.setItem("token", user)
```